# How to add views programmaticaly in tableview cell, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Please help. I want to create table view cell content absolutely programmatically. But it's not wroking ( Where I'm wrong?
My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FiltersMenuCell: UITableViewCell {
    var customFilters = [SearchRequestRestModelItem]()
    var filtersCounters: NSDictionary? = nil
    var isMyFilters = true

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

    func initFilters() {
        let customFiltersSize = customFilters.count
        var previousFilterNameLabel: UILabel? = nil
        for index in 0..<customFiltersSize {
            let filterNameLabel = UILabel()
            filterNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: Constants.regularFontName, size: 16)
            filterNameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            filterNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            filterNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            filterNameLabel.text = "My filters".localized

            mainView.addSubview(filterNameLabel)

            filterNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

            filterNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
            filterNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
            filterNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true 
            ...
```

Cell intialization:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.filtersMenuCell) as! FiltersMenuCell
            cell.isMyFilters = indexPath.row == 4

            cell.customFilters = cell.isMyFilters ? presenter!.getMyFilters(allCustomFilters: customFilters)
                    : presenter!.getSharedFilters(allCustomFilters: customFilters)
            cell.filtersCounters = allTicketsCountModel.customFiltersCounters
            cell.initFilters()

            return cell)
    }
```

Why it's not working? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more context. What do you mean by "it's not working"? What's your expected output? And what's the current output?

Comment: No filterNameLabel appears

Comment: Does your code gose inside func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?

Comment: It looks like you trying to add multiple labels? I suggest starting with adding a single label - give it a background color so you can easily see its frame. When you have that working correctly, you can edit your code to add multiple labels. Also, when you run your app and *"No filterNameLabel appears"*, use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the cell -- you may find that a label *was* added, but the text is empty, or the constraints are pushing it out of view.

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this code but a few things come t mind. If you are adding views to a cell, you need to remove them all each time cellForRowAt is called because cells get reused. Second, you need to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property on your cell to false. Third, all of your labels are using the same constraints. They should not all be placed in the same location. Lastly, your constants for top and trailing anchors should be negative values (-8) for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your constraints on views are not working, so you need to add first

```
yourMainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
yourLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   

// and add below code in you cellForRow AtIndexPath
DispatchQueue.main.async {
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: @ВладимирФишер review again. this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your filterNameLabel constraints are not properly created. You need to set the first index filterNameLabel top constraint equal to mainView top constraint. and last index filterNameLabel bottom constraint equal to mainView bottom constraint. And other constraints is relative, that means next filterNameLabel top constraint equal to previous filterNameLabel bottom constraint. Always call layout if needed method.

On the other way if you want to take another tableView inside FiltersMenuCell, you can follow these steps:

1) Create a tableView inside FiltersMenuCell class. Initialize this closure into this class.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var tableViewContentSizeHeight: CGFloat {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    return tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

2) Create "mainView" height constraint into FiltersMenuCell class globally.

```
var mainView: UIView!
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

heightConstraint = mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
```

3) Update "heightConstraint" from cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? FiltersMenuCell {
        cell.reloadData()
        cell.heightConstraint.constant = cell.tableViewContentSizeHeight
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```